# Python+Django : Bug in code looking for a 2nd insight

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have a function with the following code:

```
 if request.method == 'POST':
    company_id = request.POST.get('company_id')
    choice_list = request.POST.getlist('info[]')
    response = read_csv_lines(choice_list,company_id)
    print(response)
```

`choice_list` contains numbers selected in a list. For example `[2,3]` and the ID of a dropdown box.

This one goes to the following function (`read_csv_lines`)

```py
def read_csv_lines(my_list,company_id):
    test_file = './upload.csv'
    company = Company.objects.get(id=company_id)
    with open(test_file) as csv_file:
        file_reader = list(csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';'))
        for i in my_list:
            i = int(i)
            deviceinf = file_reader[i]
            status = add_device(deviceinf,company.auth_token,company.company_name)
```

I get the info from the company cause I need these to make an API call in a separate function
I open the file read every line but all lines in a list and for the value I read the line in the list of reading lines.
And pass this through to my API call.

What happens next is the bug.
When I launch a POST the following thing happens:
It enters the read_csv_lines. jumps right back out and print as a response "None" but the other calls keep on going and the API call in the background executes

Could someone look into this as a 2nd opinion?

Comment: 'read_csv_lines' function is not returning anything. It is normal that the response is None. Have you checked also if the `test_file` route is correct?

Comment: I just found out that the problem is due to a double call of the "POST" it seems. when printing choice_list , the first time it comes back empty ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem persisting was actually an AJAX issue:

didnt add preventDefault & Propagation

changed it up towards:

```
$('#submit_phones').click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```